# Java + TestNG - How to resolve ”has a @Test annotation but also a return value: ignoring it. Use <suite allow-return-values=”true”> to fix this”

Tags: testng, appium, mobile-automation

I execute tests, while I observed ”has a @Test annotation but also a return value: ignoring it. Use  to fix this” and execution terminated.
[My Env - Java + Maven + TestNG ]

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All test methods should be void. It's in the test assertions that confirms if your code is producing the intended output.
Example :

```
@Test
public void testAddBanana() {
//Your data setup and invocation of the add method
assertTrue(ans == result);
}
```

For more information of the different types of annotations and assertions, check the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

Comment: Good one. Accepted Adrian